Is there an example of sets $A,B$ such that $\mu_{\tau}^{*} (A) = \mu_{\tau}^{*}(B)$ but $\mu_{\tau}^{*}(B\setminus A) >0$?
I was trying to prove a theorem from my Measure Theory Assignment and i got something that i don't know if is either true or false.
It was the following: Let $\mu_{\tau}^*$ be the exterior measure generated by a pre-measure $\tau \colon \mathcal{C} \to [0,\infty]$ over a space $X$ and let $\mathcal{M}_{\mu_{\tau}^*}$ denote the class of $\mu^{*}_{\tau}$-measurable sets. Assuming that $\mathcal{C} \subseteq \mathcal{M}_{\mu_{\tau}^{*}}$, show that if $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of subsets (not necessarily measurable) in $X$ such that $A_n \subseteq A_{n+1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then
$$
\mu_{\tau}^{*}\left(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu_{\tau}^{*}(A_n).
$$
For this, i tried taking $\mu_{\tau}^{*}$-measurable sets $(B_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\mu_{\tau}^{*}(A_n) = \mu_{\tau}^{*} (B_n)$ and $A_n \subseteq B_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and then take $F_n = \bigcup_{k=1}^{n} B_k$ trying to get an increasing sequence of measurable sets to eventually use continuity from bellow and conclude.
In order to prove the above, i tried to show that $\mu_{\tau}^{*}(F_n) = \mu_{\tau}^{*}(A_n)$ by doing the following:
$$
\mu_{\tau}^{*}(F_n \setminus A_n) = \mu_{\tau}^{*} \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^{n} (B_k\setminus A_n) \right) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} \mu_{\tau}^{*}(B_k \setminus A_n) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} \mu_{\tau}^{*}(B_k\setminus A_k)
$$
Now, i reduced it to show that $\mu_{\tau}^{*} (B_k\setminus A_k) = 0$, thing that sounds absolutelly true for me in first instance, but as i thought more and more about it, i'm not sure at all.
My question is: Is there an example of sets $A,B$ such that $\mu_{\tau}^{*} (A) = \mu_{\tau}^{*}(B)$, $A$ is non-measurable and $B$ is measurable but $\mu_{\tau}^{*}(B\setminus A) >0$?

Yes there are. Let $A$ for example be a non measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure of finite outer measure. By the definition of the outer measure, you can construct a sequence $B_n$ of (Borel) sets such that $\mu^*(A)\leq \lambda(B_n) \leq \mu^*(A)+\frac{1}{n}$. If $B=\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} B_n$, then $B$ has the same outer measure as $A$. However, if $\mu^*(B\backslash A) = 0$ were to hold, then $B\backslash A$ would be a Lebesgue null set and thus Lebesgue measurable, implying that $A$ is Lebesgue measurable, which is by assumption not the case. This is precisely what stops sets from being measurable in practice.

thank you very much!
